# Daily time steps interpolation between several netcdf layers over time in R or CDO

Tags: r, netcdf, data-management, cdo-climate

I have several observations over time of a spatial variable (let's say var_A_1985.nc, var_A_2000.nc and var_A_2010.nc) with only one time layer. Would it be possible to efficiently reconstruct the daily values from 01/01/1985 to 01/01/2010 by linearly interpolating these values?

I currently explored two options:

- Climate Data Operator (CDO): I saw the operators inttime and intyear, but these do not seem to work for my case.
- R as RasterBrick element manipulation

something like:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
setwd(mypath)

var_A_1985 <- raster("var_A_1985.nc")
var_A_2000 <- raster("var_A_2000.nc")

var_A_brick <- brick(var_A_1985, var_A_2000)
brick_2<- brick(lapply(1:n_days, function(x) raster::raster(matrix(NA, nrow(var_A_1985), ncol(var_A_1985)))) #with n_days representing the number of days between 01/01/1985 and 01/01/2000
extremes<- c(1, n_days)

for (i in 1:2) {
    brick_2[[extremes[i]]]=var_A_brick[[1]]
}
var_A_brick_filled <- approxNA(brick_2, method = 'linear')
#and then write this the new netcdf with daily values
```

This second method actually works, but it takes forever. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CDO as follows:

```
cdo -inttime,1985-01-01,12:00:00,1day -mergetime var*.nc outfile
```

Adjust the start time, of course.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your reply. Not really, with this command you input just one file (so just one point in time). How do you define the end of the interpolation?

Comment: Robert's solution merges the files starting with "var" into one file with mergetime, and then applied the interpolation to the output of the mergetime command, and so will have more than one timeslice

Comment: Thanks Adrian and Robert! Just to understand if I got this correctly: step 1) I create the two var files assigning a date to them (01/01/ year1 and year2); step 2) I merge the two files (cdo -cat); step 3) I run the cdo -inttime as for Robert's suggestion. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you not just try to do this before asking?

Comment: Hi Robert, no need to get nasty: I was just trying to understand how this works. Thanks for your suggestion: I'll test it and accept your answer.